# Display success message to user

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, message

I am using ASP.net core razor engine.  I am making a registration and I want to display to the user a success message when the registration had been successful.
Here is my code

my .cs file

```
namespace login.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly UserFactory userFactory;

        public HomeController(UserFactory user) {
            userFactory = user;
        }

        // GET: /Home/
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["message"] = false;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Register(Home model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            PasswordHasher<Home> Hasher = new PasswordHasher<Home>();
            model.Password = Hasher.HashPassword(model, model.Password);
            userFactory.Add(model);
            ViewData["message"] = true;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

my html file

```
@model login.Models.Home

@using(Html.BeginForm("Register","Home"))
{
    <h1>Please Register</h1>
    <p>
       <label>Your First Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.FirstName)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Your Last Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.LastName)
    </p>
     <p>
        <label>Your Email</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Email)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Your Password</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Password)
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Confrim Password</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.PasswordConfirmation)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.PasswordConfirmation)
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!"/>
}
 @if(ViewData["message"] == "true")
      {
          <p>Success</p>
      }
```

I also changed to TempData["message"] == "false" so see if I would get any message in my html.  But the message does not renders in my html

Comment: ```if(ViewData["message"])``` it's also a boolean, not string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can utility this code:

code cs.

```
namespace login.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly UserFactory userFactory;

    public HomeController(UserFactory user) {
        userFactory = user;
    }

    // GET: /Home/
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Register(Home model)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", model);
        }
        PasswordHasher<Home> Hasher = new PasswordHasher<Home>();
        model.Password = Hasher.HashPassword(model, model.Password);
        userFactory.Add(model);
        ViewBag.message = "Success";
        return View();
       }
    }
}
```

code razor

```
@model login.Models.Home

@using(Html.BeginForm("Register","Home"))
{
 <h1>Please Register</h1>
 <p>
   <label>Your First Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.FirstName)
 </p>
<p>
    <label>Your Last Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.LastName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.LastName)
</p>
 <p>
    <label>Your Email</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Email)
</p>
<p>
    <label>Your Password</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.Password)
</p>
<p>
    <label>Confrim Password</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.PasswordConfirmation)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.PasswordConfirmation)
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register!"/>
}
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.message))
  {
      <p>@ViewBag.message</p>
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with your code.

First is that in the controllers you use `ViewData` and in the View you use `TempData` - they are different containers. Use one of them consistently.

You need to also be aware that `ViewData` only lives during the request so when you do the redirect it will go away - it looks like the more suitable would be `TempData` here.

Second is that you always set the `ViewData["message"]` to `false` in your `Index` action and after you register you do the redirect to `Index` so even if you would check the same container in your view it would yield false and the message would not show. You need to set the value to false only after you render it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you're setting `ViewData`, then checking `TempData` in the view. Update this to match and your code should work.